# recuperar contraseña firebase

Tags: firebase, contraseña

Tengo un error con la opción de recuperar contraseña, cuando hago clic en el enlace para cambiar la contraseña, la página de recuperación se actualiza automáticamente y dice: "La solicitud para cambiar la contraseña ha caducado o el enlace ya se ha utilizado". Por favor ayuda.

Comment: Estás en SO en Español, traduce la pregunta y el título.

Comment: Ok realizado...

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionarlo quitando la opcion de `Vínculo del correo electrónico (acceso sin contraseña)`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]